# Go up one Folder and after dive into other in PHP?

Tags: php

I have Folder structure like this 'site/plugin/myplugin.php' and the php is in the 'site/theme/index.php' and i want to go up into the plugin folder and access the plugin.php I go up one level like this ../ but how can I get into the same line of code to go in the plugin folder !

Thx Elod

Comment: `../plugin/` very basic

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "syntax" every OS has: `..`

So you can use the following (doesn't make sense, but i hope you get the point):

```
site/theme/../plugin/;
```

This works in Linux as well as in Windows.